# Python, print file content as matrix

Tags: python, file, matrix

If we have a file with content in type str:

"[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]"

How can we print this line as a matrix?

So the output look like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]"
for row in eval(matrix):
    print(" ".join([str(element) for element in row]))
```

Here, `" ".join(...)` joins a list of strings `...` with the separator `" "`.

Comment: This gives the following output: [ [ 1 , 2 , 3 ] , [ 4 , 5 , 6 ] , [ 7 , 8 , 9 ] ]

Comment: @John See the edit for the correct solution.